# Splitting fields from a CSV file using pyspark

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm having issues splitting a CSV file through PySpark. I'm trying to output the country and name of the wine (this is just to prove the parsing is working), but I get an error.

This is how the CSV file looks:

> ,country,description,designation,points,price,province,region_1,region_2,variety,winery
>
> 20,US,"Heitz has made this stellar rosé from the rare Grignolino grape since 1961. Ruby grapefruit-red, it's sultry with strawberry, watermelon, orange zest and salty spice flavor, highlighted with vibrant floral aromas.",Grignolino,95,24.0,California,Napa Valley,Napa,Rosé,Heitz

and here is my code

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("SQLProject")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)


def parseLine(line):
    fields = line.split(',')
    country = fields[1]
    points = fields[4]
    return country, points


lines = sc.textFile("file:///Users/luisguillermo/IE/Spark/Final Project/wine-reviews/winemag-data-130k-v2.csv")
rdd = lines.map(parseLine)

results = rdd.collect()

for result in results:
    print(result)
```

And get this error:

```
  File "/Users/luisguillermo/IE/Spark/Final Project/wine-reviews/country_and_points.py", line 10, in parseLine
    points = fields[4]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

It appears that the program gets confused as there are commas in the description. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: why not use spark's builtin CSV reader: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv.

Comment: There may be issues since you are splitting on `,`, and there are `,` in your description.

Comment: I agree with @DrChess, why not use a proper csv library for this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Spark built-in CSV data source as it provides many options including **quotes** which is used to read delimiter from columns, Ofcourse the column with delimiter should have quoted with some character.

**quotes**

When you have a column with a delimiter that used to split the columns, use quotes option to specify the quote character, by default it is ” and delimiters inside quotes are ignored. but using this option you can set any character.

If you wanted to read other options Spark CSV provides along with examples, I would suggest reading the following articles.

[spark-read-csv-file-into-dataframe](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-read-csv-file-into-dataframe/)

[read-csv](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/read-csv.html)

Happy Learning !!

Answer (score 0):

See this code:

```
df = spark.read\
    .csv('data.csv')

df.printSchema()
df.show()
```

The resulting df is a DataFrame with the columns just like the CSV.
See more advance features [here](https://roizaig.blogspot.com/2019/10/spark-read-csv-file.html)